# Android Studio Bot Unexpected network error in Android Studio Hedgehog Canary

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, intellij-plugin

I signed in to my Google account in `Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Canary 4`, then opened the Studio Bot for the first time. Everything I ask, throws an exception like:

```
Unexpected network error, please try again later.
Error: Status UNAVAILABLE io exception Channel Pipeline: [HttpProxyHandler$HttpClientCodecWrapper#0, HttpProxyHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ProxyProtocolNegotiationHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
```

[image]